# Subtle bugs in implementing circular queue

Tags: c, queue

i am trying to implement a simple circular queue operation as below

```
void push(int theElement)
{
  //Check if the push causes queue to overflow
    if  (((queueBack + 1 ) % arrayLength) == queueFront) {
       std::cout<<"Queue is full."<<std::endl;
       return ;
    } 
    queueBack = (queueBack + 1) % arrayLength;
    inputArray[queueBack] = theElement;
}

int pop()
{
   //Check if queue  is already empty
  if ( queueFront == queueBack ) {
    std::cout<<"Queue is empty."<<std::endl;
    return;
  }
  queueFront = (queueFront + 1 ) % arrayLength;
  return inputArray[queueFront];

}
```

Considering initially queueFront = 0 and queueBack = 0,
The above code results in a full queue even though actually it isn't. How do i correct this? Is my implementation correct in the first case?

Test cases
Initially arrayLength = 3, queueFront = 0, queueBack = 0;

1. At the end of first call to push(1) ; queueFront = 0 , queueBack = 1 , 1 gets added to inputArray[1] rather than 0;
2. At the end of second call to push(2), queueFront = 0, queueBack = 2, , 2 gets added to inputArray[2],
3. Now , (queueBack + 1) % arrayLength == queueFront is true, whereas there is one more empty space left i.e., inputArray[0] .

Thanks

Comment: can you explain with some input values what problem this code is giving? and what you meant by it gives full queue when it is not full?

Comment: As you are using c++, you should encapsulate the functionality into a class rather that using global variables. Even in C using globals for this it's bad style.

Comment: Agree @MichaelWalz, but lets forget the intricacies for a while. I would like to first come up with the correct logic.

Comment: As you explain in yourquestion under point 1, 1 gets added to inputArray[1] rather than to inputArray[0], well that's obvious, yun incremented queueBack before.

Comment: I just noticed that your variable names are non-standard.  Typically, the queueFront is advanced as items are pushed, and the queueBack is advanced as items are popped, i.e. the back follows the front.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's a feature of circular queues. If you don't leave one empty slot, then there's no way to distinguish between the full and empty cases.  Of course, the pop function should return the int that it read from the queue, and there's no need to set the value to -1.

Comment: In this case, setting the value to -1 is a bug since it is done *after* `queueFront` has been incremented (so it stomps on the next element).

Comment: Not true, since OP pre-increments both pointers, there is no bug.  I agree that it's more intuitive to post-increment, but if OP replaces the last line with a return statement (to return the value) then you can see that pre-incrementing is in fact more efficient.

Comment: Ah, I see now.  My bad.

Comment: @user3386109 , i have modified the pop() function, is it correct now?